# Internet & Email Sharing

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet

I have a workgroup of ten computers connected to internet on a broadband ADSL line via a 24 port switch. There is no server.

The internet bills have gone so high that I want to eliminate seven to email only and no internet leaving three that can have access to internet.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Please don't double post.

Comment: What email provider do you use?

Comment: This won't be possible with a simple networking switch.  Besides you can't email with an internet connection

Answer (score 1):

Given that you still need internet to use email, I'm assuming what you really want is to eliminate **web browsing** on the group of seven computers.

You have several options:

- Remove any third party browsers and disable Internet Explorer in Control Panel > Products and Features > Windows Features. You could also add file permissions to the Internet Explorer executable that would not allow it to launch without an administrator password.
- Set the group of seven computers' network adapters to use 127.0.0.1 as their only DNS server, and use the [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) to add the DNS records for your email provider's sending and receiving server addresses, or add the whole domain of your email provider if you use webmail.
- Use some sort of parental controls - like a DNS or a third party program - to whitelist your email provider and nothing else.

---

#### Alternative Solution:

Assuming that you have an internet provider that charges based on data consumption (and not just a flat rate per month), I would suggest finding out what the source of the high data usage is.

1. Use a [internet monitoring tool](http://www.paessler.com/network_monitoring_tool) in your network to find out who is using the most data, and what the source of that data is. You may find that someone is streaming Pandora or YouTube 24/7, or downloading things they shouldn't be, and simply blocking that content may solve the problem.
2. There are plenty of web filtering services (like [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/)) that allow you to block content like Facebook, YouTube or music streaming sites. Music and video consume the most data. I'm going on a limb guessing that your network is in an office, so it would make sense to block websites that are not work related.

Comment: Or, if you are (still) using Internet Explorer 6, just set the homepage to `ms-its:%F0:`.

Comment: Or Google Chrome, on which you can set it to `chrome://inducebrowsercrashforrealz`.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this with the Windows Firewall.  Just block ports normally used in browsing, or only allow ports used for email.

Control Panel > Windows Firewall > Advanced Settings.
For browsing, you're likely most concerned about outbound rules, although there are 14 different ways to go about getting the results you want.  Select Outbound, and click on "New Rule";  here you can block by program, port, or custom parameters.  For example, to block Internet Explorer, you can block the program "iexplorer.exe", or you can block ports 80 and 8080 and any others associated with use of a browser.

For email, the ports will depend on the email configuration.  i.e. gmail's ssl uses port 995 incoming & 587 for outgoing via TLS.  The most common is SMTP port 25 for sending, and 110 for POP3.  You can find out which ports you need open by checking the email provider's site for configuration of mail clients, or by checking the actual configuration of one of your email client programs.

All this assumes that your staff doesn't read email through some webmail interface, of course.  If they do use webmail, you'll instead need to block virtually all sites except the one used, rather than blocking ports.

This is at least a free option & relatively easy to configure, plus there is a lot of documentation available on how to use the built-in feature.

=======
BUT, you know, I have to wonder -- you are paying for internet service based on usage?  Otherwise, blocking access won't lower your bill at all.